# Using Firebase in Native Script

Tags: telerik, firebase, nativescript

I went through the documentation at [Native Script](https://www.nativescript.org/) but could find a way to use Firebase in Native Script apps.
Does any one know how to use Firebase in Native Script apps?

Comment: That looks similar to ReactNative, which means that this post is probably relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aoPNvQQsVUE. Essentialy it boils down to: Firebase uses websockets for its communication; if ReactNative implements websockets, there is a chance it may work. Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/NativeScript/cross-platform-modules/issues/145

Comment: Nothin yet @FrankvanPuffelen ..

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Note: This is just a copy and paste of my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33969147/).</sup>

I've just built [nativescript-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-firebase), which is loads the Firebase Node.js SDK in a way that's compatible with NativeScript.

Also, Eddy Verbruggen has written [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/eddyverbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) which uses Firebase's corresponding Android and iOS SDKs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) plugin which supports **iOS** and **Android**.

Plugin features following:

- Realtime Database
- Authentication
- Remote Config
- Cloud Messaging
- Storage
- Crash Reporting
- Analytics

I have been using this plugin for FCM for ios and Android.

Regards.