# Integrate firebase with nativescript

Tags: firebase, nativescript

Firebase has an Android library. How can I integrate with nativescript?
There is no tutorial out there. I really need help for the setup and how to call those api.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869747/using-firebase-in-native-script (no answer there, but same question)

Comment: readme file : https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 4):

I've just built [nativescript-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-firebase), which is loads the Firebase Node.js SDK in a way that's compatible with NativeScript.

Also, Eddy Verbruggen has written [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/eddyverbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase) which uses Firebase's corresponding Android and iOS SDKs.

Comment: LOL, I only saw your plugin just now. Cool job, folks have something to choose from now. Thanks for your work!

Comment: All good :) yeah it's good to have both options I think - it'll be interesting to see what the advantages of each approach are.

Comment: lol, nice. Here they are, the two authors. Thanks a lot Matt Lyons and @EddyVerbruggen